# Select body from bigquery reddit data only when parent data body exists?

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery

In the big query reddit data, there is a body of the comment, a comment id, and a parent comment id. I need a query that can run in big query. (I state this because standard big query syntax misses a couple SQL statement things like "while") This statement needs to select the body of a comment only when the parent comment is not null.

So basically the query needs to read the first row, find that comments parent id, check the database to see if that comment id has a body that is not empty, and if so return a database where each row is just {column one is the comment body} {column two is the parent body}

I've tried thinking like "SELECT ***parent_id***, body FROM `table` WHERE (SELECT body FROM `table` WHERE id = ***parent_id***) != NULL"

The above statement would work if I could find a way where the ***parent_id***'s would be the same thing. Any help?

EDIT:

SELECT SPLIT(parent_id, "_")[OFFSET(1)] as q1, body FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2008` WHERE (SELECT body from `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2008` where id = q1) != null

This query would work if it would set parent_id as a variable type thing called q1, and use it later as q1.

Any help on getting this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use INNER JOIN...

```
SELECT
  t1.body
  t1.parent_id,
  t2.body AS parent_body
FROM
  `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2008` t1
INNER JOIN
  `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2008` t2
ON
  SPLIT(t1.parent_id, '_')[ OFFSET (1)] = t2.id
WHERE
  t2.body IS NOT NULL
```